# What is the indefinite integral of $\frac{4^x}{e^x}$?

Tags: integration

What is the indefinite integral of $\frac{4^x}{e^x}$? Can anyone can show a step by step solution for this problem?

Comment: First and almost last step, $4^x=e^{x\ln(4)}$, so our function is $e^{x(\ln (4)-1)}$.

Comment: You could also treat this as $$ \ \int \ \left(\frac{4}{e} \right)^x \ \ dx \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{\ln (4/e)} \ \left(\frac{4}{e}\right)^x \ + \ C \ \ , $$ using the rule for integrating exponential functions $ \ a^x \ $   .

Comment: Could I just say then that e^[x(ln(4)-1)] + c is the answer ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use that $\frac{4^x}{e^x}=\left(\frac{4}{e}\right)^x$, and that $\int a^x dx=\frac{a^x}{\ln a}+C$

Answer (score 0):

Hera's the step by step .Just remember that $a^x = e^{(ln(a))^x} = e^{x*ln(a)}$

$\int \frac{4^x}{e^x} = \int (\frac{4}{e})^x  =  \int e^{ln (\frac{4}{e})^x} = \int e^{xln (\frac{4}{e})} = \frac{e^{xln\frac{4}{e}}}{ln\frac{4}{e}} = \frac{e^{(ln\frac{4}{e})^x}}{ln\frac{4}{e}}  = \frac{\frac{4}{e}^x}{ln\frac{4}{e}}  $